# Нужна ли запятая перед тире

Tags: пунктуация

Пожалуй, запятые перед тире - один из камней преткновения в русском языке. А как быть с этим предложением: "Думаю, то, что есть сейчас(,) — наиболее выигрышный вариант"? Нужна тут запятая или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, запятая нужна, потому что она выделяет придаточную часть внутри главной, в которой между подлежащим (*то*) и сказуемым (*вариант*) ставится тире.