# Нужна ли после слова "судьба" запятая? (запятая перед тире)

Tags: пунктуация

> Самый лучший подарок, который дарит нам судьба - это люди, которым мы говорим "спасибо, что ты есть".

Нужна ли после слова "судьба" запятая?

Comment: схожий вопрос: **[запятая перед тире](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5)**

Comment: еще один схожий вопрос: **[нужна ли запятая перед тире](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4590/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5)**

Answer (score 5):

Запятая ставится перед связкой ЭТО, если она закрывает определительный оборот или придаточное предложение:

Самый лучший подарок, который дарит нам судьба, - это люди, которым мы говорим "спасибо, что ты есть".

Сравнить: Птицы, зимующие у нас, – это синичка, снегирь.